# Beta Badge Clarification

Tags: support, badges, private-beta

The Beta badge is achieved by "Actively participating in the private beta."  Does that mean the private beta for Stack Overflow (which I believe never happened) or just any site on the Stack Exchange network?

Answer (score 12):

There was a private beta for Stack Overflow - it was in July 2008!

The badge is site-specific, so you get it for a site when you participate in the private beta for *that* site. It's way too late to get it for Stack Overflow, but if you commit to a site on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and ask and answer questions in its private beta, you'll get the badge for that site.